# How do I make the bar width on Chartist.js responsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, bar-chart

How do I make the bar width on Chartist.js responsive, so that the bars are wider when there is more space for them to "grow".

- Without converting the data into a series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a plugin that solves this issue.

You can adjust the `0.7` until the widths of the bars and the spacing between each bar is just right. It will then adjust the `stroke_width` based on the width of the canvas/chart.

```
import Chartist from 'chartist';

const pluginDynamicBarWidth = (optionProps) => (chart) => {

  Chartist.extend({}, {}, optionProps);

  chart.on('draw', (data) => {
    const numberOfLabels = optionProps;
    const chartWidth = chart.container.clientWidth;
    const canvas = chartWidth * 0.7;
    const strokeWidth = canvas / numberOfLabels;

    if (data.type === 'bar') {
      data.element._node.style.strokeWidth = `${strokeWidth}px`;
    }
  });
};

export default pluginDynamicBarWidth;
```